# Return the list of items which are part of the longest path from Tree's root to a Leaf in a General Tree

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, tree, longest-path

Given this Class that represents a tree , i got a little confused on how would i return a list that will consist of nodes that are part of the tree's height .

```
public class TreeNode<T>
    {

        private T m_Data;
        public T Data
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Data;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Data = value;
            }
        }
        private readonly List<TreeNode<T>> m_Children;
        public List<TreeNode<T>> Children
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Children;
            }
        }

        public TreeNode(T i_Data)
        {
            this.m_Data = i_Data;
            m_Children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
        }

        public void AddChild(T data)
        {
            m_Children.Add(new TreeNode<T>(data));
           // return m_Children[m_Children.Count-1];
        }

        public List<T> LongestPathNodes(TreeNode<T> i_node)//this function
        {
            if(i_node.m_Children.Count == 0)
            {
                List<T> choosenMove = new List<T>(1);
                choosenMove.Add(i_node.Data);
                return choosenMove;

            }
            else
            {
                foreach(TreeNode<T> treeNode in i_node.Children)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

The function which i'm talking about is the "LongestPathNodes" Function ,I think it has to be recursive ,  i wrote part of it but i'm confused on how should i proceed , given the fact that the tree does not have to be a binary one .

Comment: *"I think it has to be recursive"* is incorrect, given that any recursive function can be written as an iterative one.

Comment: You are right , but i think the intuitive approach to working with Trees is Recursion .

Answer (score 1):

Define a `Height` property:

```
public int Height =>
    m_Children != null && m_Children.Any()
    ? m_Children.Max(x => x.Height) + 1
    : 1;
```

Now you can return the nodes of the longest branch from any given node:

```
public IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> LongestPathNodes()
{
    yield return this;
    var children = m_Children?
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Height)
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .LongestPathNodes();
    if (children != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in children) yield return child;
    }
}
```

If you need this as a `List<T>` it is a LINQ one-liner:

```
var list = node.LongestPathNodes().Select(x => x.m__Data).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to C# syntax (tho i come from C++ and C) so your solution might be right , but it will take time till i understand it fully  . I was hoping for something more simpler . (:

Comment: @ArtemKuznetsov I'm not sure you can simplify this much; it isn't a trivial problem.